# InteractiveTradingChart and ChartElementFunction

Tags: plotting, bugs, charts, finance

I want to plot a similar candlestick chart as on the picture below with blue down-candles and white up-candles with blue edges.

[image]

With `TrendStyle -> {White, Blue}` I don't see shadows on up-candles because they are white.

```
InteractiveTradingChart[
 {
  {{2015, 7, 8, 10, 0, 0}, {1, 3, 0, 2, 100}},
  {{2015, 7, 8, 10, 0, 1}, {2, 3, 0, 1, 200}}
  },
 TrendStyle -> {GrayLevel[.9](*White*), Blue},
 ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[Blue],
 PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"
 ]
```

[image]

As I understand, I need to use `ChartElementFunction`. When I tried to find out how to do it, I found a bug. This is an example from documentation for `TradingChart`:

```
zigzag[{{x0_, x1_}, {y0_, y1_}}, {o_, h_, l_, c_}, __] := If[o < c,
  Line[Transpose[{x0 + {0, 1/3, 2/3, 1}*(x1 - x0), {o, l, h, c}}]], 
  Line[Transpose[{x0 + {0, 1/3, 2/3, 1}*(x1 - x0), {o, h, l, c}}]]
  ]

TradingChart[
 {
  {{2015, 7, 8, 10, 0, 0}, {1, 3, 0, 2, 100}},
  {{2015, 7, 8, 10, 0, 1}, {2, 3, 0, 1, 200}}
  },
 ChartElementFunction -> zigzag
 ]
```

[image]

But for `InteractiveTradingChart` `ChartElementFunction` doesn't work.

```
InteractiveTradingChart[
 {
  {{2015, 7, 8, 10, 0, 0}, {1, 3, 0, 2, 100}},
  {{2015, 7, 8, 10, 0, 1}, {2, 3, 0, 1, 200}}
  },
 ChartElementFunction -> zigzag
 ]
```

[image]

Is there another way to plot candlestick chart as I want?

Comment: does this work: `InteractiveTradingChart[{{{2015, 7, 8, 10, 0, 0}, {1, 3, 0, 2, 
    100}}, {{2015, 7, 8, 10, 0, 1}, {2, 3, 0, 1, 200}}}, 
 TrendStyle -> {FaceForm[White], Blue}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
 ChartBaseStyle -> Directive[Blue, EdgeForm[Blue]]]`?

Comment: @kglr Yes, this works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use a custom `ChartElementFunction` if you use the following settings for the options `TrendStyle` and `ChartBaseStyle`:

```
InteractiveTradingChart[{{{2015, 7, 8, 10, 0, 0}, {1, 3, 0, 2, 100}}, 
  {{2015, 7, 8, 10, 0, 1}, {2, 3, 0, 1, 200}}}, 
 TrendStyle -> {FaceForm[White], Blue}, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
 ChartBaseStyle -> Directive[Blue, EdgeForm[Blue]]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, (in version 9.0 - windows 10) you can remove the option `ChartBaseStyle` and use

```
TrendStyle -> {Directive[Blue, EdgeForm[Blue], FaceForm[White]], Blue}
```

to get the same picture.

Comment: With `TrendStyle -> {Directive[Blue, EdgeForm[Blue], FaceForm[White]], Blue}` it renders incorrectly. https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAKWK.png

Comment: @AlexeyGolyshev, it must be version-dependent. Both work in version 9.0 (windows 10).

Answer (score 2):

#### Update

When I look at the documentation for which you provide a link, I see

```
zigzag[{{x0_, x1_}, {y0_, y1_}}, {o_, h_, l_, c_}, __] := 
  If[o < c, 
    Line[Transpose[{x0 + {0, 1/3, 2/3, 1}*(x1 - x0), {o, l, h, c}}]], 
    Line[Transpose[{x0 + {0, 1/3, 2/3, 1}*(x1 - x0), {o, h, l, c}}]]]
```

which looks perfectly OK to me. And as your `TradingChart` example produces exactly what it should, I see no evidence there is a bug.

Is your question about `TradingChart` or about `InteractiveTradingChart`?
As far as I can tell, both functions work OK. However, the ***documentation*** for `InteractiveTradingChart` has problems. It seems to be a copy and paste from `TradingChart` without proper editing. There is quite a bit of that in the V10.1 docs. So you might report a documentation bug to WRI.

Since `InteractiveTradingChart` appears to ignore the `ChartElementFunction` option, if you want to have a custom chart element function, use `TradingChart`.

```
chartElementFunction[{{x0_, x1_}, {y0_, y1_}}, {o_, h_, l_, c_}, __] :=
  Module[{mid, top, btm, color},
    mid = x0 + (x1 - x0)/2;
    If[o < c,
      color = White; {top, btm} = {c, o},
      color = Blue; {top, btm} = {o, c}];
    {Blue, Thick, Line[{{mid, y0}, {mid, y1}}], 
     EdgeForm[Blue], color, Rectangle[{x0, btm}, {x1, top}]}]

TradingChart[{
  {{2015, 7, 8, 10, 0, 0}, {1, 3, 0, 2, 100}}, 
  {{2015, 7, 8, 10, 0, 1}, {2, 3, 0, 1, 200}}}, 
  ChartElementFunction -> chartElementFunction,
  BarSpacing -> Tiny]
```

[image: chart]